# "Google Offline Mail Background Page" keeps opening

Tags: gmail, offline

Every 30 seconds or so while I'm browsing in Chrome, a new window calling itself "Google Offline Mail Background Page" keeps opening and then doesn't load.

It appears like this:

[image: Google Offline Mail Background Page]

I close it and it re-opens. Any understanding of what is causing these?

Comment: I've seen the same thing on my Chromebook after a small update to Chrome yesterday. I suspect it's a bug that will get fixed shortly. I've seen no serious side effects so far. I've been able to just close it and keep working.

Comment: I was also seeing it at home last night. I agree with Folk's assessment that it's probably a bug that'll get fixed soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it was a bug. As stated on the [Google product forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/gmail/H8bi1RvmXWs/CJcJg6l3BgAJ),

> The issue should now be fixed.  Please clear your browser's cache and cookies.  If the problem still persists, kindly confirm whether, in Chrome Extensions, you have Gmail Offline enabled or not.